# Laravel passport unauthenticated message

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I've been hitting wall for a while now with this, simply I can't get it where is the problem. So I've got backend Laravel and front Vue; logging in is alright, I get token but when I get into one of the routes with `auth:api` I get `"message":"Unauthenticated."`. I save token on the front, so should I send it with any request to backend or there is other way around it?

LoginController.php

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $login = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt($login))
        {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid login']);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $accessToken = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }
```

api.php

```
Route::namespace('\\')->middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('budget', BudgetController::class);
});
```

user.js

```
const state = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
    isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null
}

const getters = {
    isAuthenticated: state => state.isAuthenticated
}

const actions = {
    async retrieveToken({commit}, payload){
       console.log(payload)
        const response = axios.post(url + '/login', payload)
            .then(response => {
                const token = response.data.access_token

                localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)

                commit('setToken', token)
            })
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setToken: (token) => state.token = token
}
```

Comment: Send in `Authorization` header as `Bearer` token with every request that requires authentication.

const token = '..your token..'

axios.post(url, {
  //...data
}, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` 
  }
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so simply in my second module I used token as a header like this:

```
const state = {
  budget: [],
  header: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access_token") || null}`,
      withCredentials: true,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
  }
};


const getters = {
  allBudget: (state) => state.budget,
};

const actions = {
  async fetchBudget({ commit, state }) {
    const response = await axios.get(url, state.header);

    console.log(state.header);
    commit("setBudget", response.data);
  },
};
```

After that I was getting CORS error so i needed to add two directives at the end of the file xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * 

Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
```